# CUDA NSight 7.0 with c++11 support - where to set?

Tags: c++11, cuda, nsight

finally NVIDIA supports in CUDA 7.0 the c++11 standard even in the device code. I installed now CUDA NSight 7.0 and I am apparently too blind to find the option which activates `c++11`. For the moment I had to rename `nvcc` to `nvcc.orig` and create a shell script `nvcc` in which I call `nvcc.orig` and provide the `c++11` option with all parameters. Then I can compile my code without a problem.

But this cannot work like this!

Can somebody tell me where to activate the c++11 standard in the project settings?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure which build you mean about nsight, but here maybe what you need:

- Nsight Visual Studio

  - Project' Property Page -> CUDA C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options
  - Add your c++11 support flag: `--std=c++11`
- Nsight Eclipse

  - Project's Properties -> Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> NVCC Compiler -> Command line prompt
  - Add your c++11 support flag: `--std=c++11`

Hope this helps. Also note, nvcc support not only c++11 in host code, but also c++ in kernel code [device code], really cool~

Thanks
An

Comment: No, it does not help! I receive this error when compiling cuda source file: 4.9.2/include/stddef.h(432): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

Comment: In the most recent Nsight there is an option for that: 
Right click on the Project (not the file!) go to Build > Settings > Tab: Tool Settings > NVCC Compiler > Code Generation > Enable Checkbox: Enable C++11 support.

Answer (score 2):

This did not work for me.

> Project's Properties -> Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> NVCC Compiler -> Command line prompt. Add your c++11 support flag: --std=c++11

This worked for me

> Project's Properties > Build > Settings > Tab: Tool Settings > NVCC Compiler > Code Generation > Enable Checkbox: Enable C++11 support.

Answer (score 0):

In NSIGHT 8 this work for GCC, but not for NVCC:

- Project's Properties -> Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings 
  **-> GCC C++ Compiler** 
  -> Command line prompt. Add your c++11 support flag: --std=c++11

Answer (score 0):

This works:

Right click on your Project_name :
 Select Properties-> Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> NVCC Compiler -> Code Generation .

Tick the below-mentioned option:
             Enable C++11 support(-std=c++11)